# Making a co-occurrence matrix from mysql database in MYSQL, PHP or R

Tags: php, mysql, r, matrix

I have a mysql table that looks like this:

```
id       uid
1         a
1         b
1         c
1         d
2         a
2         b
2         c
2         e
3         b
3         c 
3         e
3         f
```

And I would like to group by id and make a co-occurrence matrix like this:

```
a,b,2   -because a and b appear together in 2 id-groups (in 1 and 2)
a,c,2   -because a and c appear together in 2 id-groups (in 1 and 2)
b,c,3   -because b and c appear together in 3 id groups (in 1, 2 and 3)
```

I am open to suggestions either in MYSQL queries, or using R or PHP.

Comment: Please show what you have tried up to now as questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Group a self-join:

```sql
SELECT   a.uid a, b.uid b, COUNT(*) cnt
FROM     my_table a JOIN my_table b ON b.id = a.id AND b.uid > a.uid
GROUP BY a.uid, b.uid
```

See it on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bde40/8/0).