# Pig Latin Inner Join to perform Co-Occurence Matrix

Tags: sql, apache-pig, self-join, unpivot

I'm going to piggy back on a closed case already in Stack overflow

[Making a co-occurrence matrix from mysql database in MYSQL, PHP or R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20034782/making-a-co-occurrence-matrix-from-mysql-database-in-mysql-php-or-r)

There is a nice solution for creating a co-occurence matrix in sql as:

```
SELECT   a.uid first_uid, b.uid second_uid, COUNT(*) cnt
FROM     my_table a JOIN my_table b ON b.id = a.id AND b.uid > a.uid
GROUP BY a.uid, b.uid
```

given a table:

```
id       uid
1         a
1         b
1         c
2         a
2         b
2         c
3         b
3         c
```

results in a co-occurrence matrix like this:

```
first_uid    second_uid    cnt
     a           b           2   
     a           c           2   
     b           c           3
```

This can also be done using SQL server unpivot command.
I am wondering how we can implement a similar solution with Pig Latin. In particular is there a way to do a join with inequality in Pig Latin.

What other alternative ways are there to get a co-occurrence matrix using PIG

Comment: Could you add an example of what exactly you're trying to achieve? It would help make the question clearer.

Comment: The end goal is to produce a co-occurance matrix using PIG. I have presented a way to do it in SQL but point out to why this strategy does not work with PIG due to its join limitation.

Answer (score 0):

The key part in your question appears to be:

> is there a way to do a join with inequality in Pig\

The answer is yes, but not always in a nice way.

The way to approach this is to first join without the condition, and then filter the result on the inequality.

Usually pig will be able to push the filter up a bit to prevent the temporary result from exploding, but I am unsure on how efficient this is in general.